# populating a unite gallery using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, image-gallery

Hi i am currently trying to populate a unite gallery using ajax however the gallery is just hanging with a loading icon and not displaying any of the images any help with be appreciated

Ajax

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var folder = "http://localhost/client%20side%20web%20coursework/files/";

    jQuery("#gallery").unitegallery();

    $.ajax({
        url: folder,
        asynch: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
                    $("#gallery").append("<img alt='uploaded file' src='" + folder + val + "'data-image='" + folder + val + "'data-description='uploaded file by user'>'");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

div we are trying to populate

```
<div id="gallery" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

the documentation for unite gallery can be found here for anyone who is not familiar with it http://unitegallery.net/index.php?page=documentation#installing_the_gallery

Any help will be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var folder = "http://localhost/client%20side%20web%20coursework/files/";
    $.ajax({
        url : folder,
        asynch : false,
        cache : false,
        success: function (data) {
            var $gallery = $("#gallery");
            var imgsToAppend = '';
            $(data).find("a").each(function(i, el) {
                var val = $(el).attr('href');
                if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
                    imgsToAppend+="<img alt='uploaded file' src='" + folder + val + "' data-image='" + folder + val + "' data-description='uploaded file by user'>";
                }
            });
            if(imgsToAppend){
                $gallery.append(imgsToAppend);
            }
            $gallery.unitegallery();
        }
    });
});
```

This solved the problem. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: This works well if you need to call your ajax request only one time in your application. I told you to see if there where an api function for the plugin to refresh the images, to avoid reinitializing it for every ajax call. But if you have just one ajax call this is the best way

Comment: Hi ciro yes in our situation we only need to call the ajax request once so this solution is suitable thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You make a ajax request to the folder wich contains your images? is there a index.php or a index.html wich retruns you a html?
You have some useless additional quotes in your .append argument, try with this :

```
$("#gallery").append("<img alt='uploaded file' src='" + folder + val + "' data-image='" + folder + val + "' data-description='uploaded file by user'>");
```

And do a console.log(data) after the ajax response, if you have nothing, add the error calback to your ajax function and console.log the error, or see the response in your browser console in the network tab

**EDIT**

I think that the jQuery .find function doesn't accept any callback arguments, you would use the .each function:

```
var $gallery = $("#gallery");
$(data).find("a").each(function(i, el) {
    var val = $(el).attr('href');
    if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
        $gallery.append("<img alt='uploaded file' src='" + folder + val + "' data-image='" + folder + val + "' data-description='uploaded file by user'>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Ciro i did what you recommended and added a image to the original question to show the results

Comment: what do you have if you go to this link? http://localhost/website/files/

Comment: because you make the ajax to this page, but I'm not sure that the page exists

Comment: hi ciro I changed my workspace to one of my old websites so i had a better visual representation of what is happening so the link is indeed different however that location still exists as can be seen in this image http://prntscr.com/hhdgi5

Comment: I edited my answer, I think that the jQuery find function doesn't accept callbacks

Comment: Hi ciro the editted code you provided makes the gallery disappear entirely

Comment: nevermind i messed up the brackets it seems to just be giving the same results as before http://prntscr.com/hhdtvv

Comment: Maybe the plugin that you use doesn't refresh the content after the ajax call automatically. Are the images appended to the dom? You can verify from the dom inspector of your debugging console, look at the bottom of the gallery container to see if your images are been appended. If yes, the problem is the plugin, you have to find how to reload  the function, maybe in some api command of the plugin

Comment: hi ciro http://prntscr.com/hhdyid as this image shows they do not seem to being appended to the div after the ajax call is successful